# How to extract email ids from people distribution list?

Tags: outlook, outlook-2010

We have a people distribution list where I am part of it. As I am not the owner of the list, I could not extract list of emails ids into csv file.

How to extract all the email ids from the PDL where I am not the owner of it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot access a private distribution list, you cannot access its members. For a private distribution list, the dl is expanded when a message is sent. No traces  of the PDL exist for the recipients.

Comment: I can access the list and see the members in it. As I am not the owner, I cannot export the members email id's to csv file.

Comment: Where exactly do you see it? If you can see the members in Outlook, you can access them programmatically.